# How do I need to vary my gameplay in order to be able to view all of the different lore and dialog in Dishonored 2?

Tags: dishonored-2

I just finished my first play through of Dishonored 2, using Corvo as a character and a low-chaos and stealth approach (actually got the [Shadow](https://dishonored-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Dishonored_2_achievements#Shadow)/[Clean Hands](https://dishonored-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Dishonored_2_achievements#Shadow) achievements combo).

I know ([reference](https://dishonored.fandom.com/wiki/Dishonored_2#Story)) that a different character/play style combination changes the outcome from the story.

I have just started a New Game+ play through, this time with Emily and aiming for as high-chaos as possible, but I've noticed that all her dialog (including her personal thoughts and reactions to the game world) seems to be very deadly/aggressive in nature, which made me wonder how deep the play style actually affects the dialog/lore.

My question is: what combination of character and play styles would I need to replay to actually see all the content? And in addition, for those who attempted it, is it worth the effort to experience the impact it has on the general lore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get different dialogue depending on choice of character and current chaos level, not limited to direct choice consequences - i.e. how you resolve specific objectives and side characters.

The Dust District and Crack in the Slab missions also have more than two final outcomes.

So if you want to see *everything* you'll need four complete playthroughs, and multiple additional repeats of missions for every permutation of actions.

I suggest that it's not worth it. Most of the major stuff is available on YouTube to have a look at separately.

With regards to lore, the canon events are:

> Corvo is turned to stone
>  Emily is marked by the Outsider
>  Alexandria Hypatia is cured
>  Kirin Jindosh is killed
>  Breanna Ashworth is spared
>  Aramis Stilton is saved
>  Duke Abele's double takes his place
>  Delilah is trapped in her painting
>  Corvo is reanimated
>  Overall low chaos

Comment: Just as an example, if you play as Corvo, help Mindy, then side with the Howlers in the Dust District, you will get different dialog with her depending on whether you accepted the Mark or not.